UI elements in Canvas not displayed when using World View
I'm  currently trying to attach text to a gameobject in a unity project. The text is displayed when I set the rendering to "Screen Space", however it's not when I use "World Space"(which is the correct rendering in my case, I believe).
I've made sure the scale of the canvas is aligned with the gameobject's size.




If anyone knows how to fix this that would be super awesome

can you add the scene view of camera at runtime, are you sure its inside the bounds of the camera? it also sounds potentially tiny

Firstly,
your 3D object is very small, meanwhile the canvas is 1200+ pixels in width and 866 pixels in height. When you use world position in the Render Mode, Unity interprets those values as a scale, just like any other GameObject in the scene. Additionally, your Canvas is inside an object, which means you have to work with local positions or scales.
Don't forget,
When using a Canvas in Unity, its dimensions depend on its Render Mode setting (e.g., Screen Space Overlay, Screen Space Camera or World Space). The Canvas behaves differently based on this mode. In World Space mode, the Canvas behaves like a regular GameObject object in the scene. Its Transform properties (i.e positions, rotations, scale etc..) are relative to the Unity world space, just like any other GameObject.
Check out theese document (https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/UICanvas.html)
